# Transistor which opens circuit, reverse transistor

Tags: transistors

I'm wondering if there is a transistor which, when a voltage is applied to the base / gate, opens the circuit instead of closing it. If there is not, how would such a configuration be created?

EDIT:
Okay, here's some clarification. I have a circuit set up like  this:

```
Motor-------------Nmos-------------Gnd
                   |
                   |
            voltage from IC
```

Currently, I am supplying a voltage to the gate of the nmos from my arduino and controlling the motor that way. I want to replace the nmos with something which will perform oppositely. As the voltage increases on it, the current between motor and gnd should decrease.

I hope that helps clarify.

Comment: Are you asking exclusively for a one component solution or for a circuit too?

Comment: Standard NPN. Connect base to a reference voltage - say 0.8V. Apply drive to emitter. As Vemitter rises transistor will turn off. Main issue is that drive input must sink load current when transistor is on.

Comment: You say the current should decrease, does this mean that you are not looking for an ON/OFF switch but a circuit that gradually limits the current? Where does the voltage from IC come from , is a a variable DC (like filtered PWM)?

Comment: The voltage is a PWM signal. And I'm looking for a circuit which acts just like a normal transistor but opposite, so a high voltage is off, and a low voltage is on, and a voltage in between is between current.

Comment: "I want to replace the nmos with something which will perform oppositely." Why not change the program in your microcontroller?

Comment: @jippie - I would, but I want it to be a safety, so if I lose power in the IC, or if the IC breaks or overheats, the motor goes to full power by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a circuit that is on by default and turns off when you apply voltage to the input.

[image]

When the input is floating or grounded Q2 is off so R2 works as a pullup resistor that turns Q1 on.

When there is a positive voltage applied to the input then Q2 turns on and sinks current trough R2, that creates a voltage drop across R2 that drops the voltage applied to the base of Q1 and turns it off.

It can also be done with mosfets with a similar logic.

Answer (score 4):

A [depletion](http://learnabout-electronics.org/fet_05.php) MOSFET does what you want. An [enhancement](http://learnabout-electronics.org/fet_04.php) MOSFET is the more common type that needs a gate-to-source voltage to start conducting.

The delpletion mosfet characteristics can be seen in the following graph
[image]

And the comparison between a depletion and enhancement N mosfet in the following graph

[image]

Images taken from [An introduction to depletion-mode MOSFETs](http://www.planetanalog.com/document.asp?doc_id=527454)

Comment: Does that require that I use a negative voltage?

Comment: Negative voltage is a relative concept. It depends on your circuit.

Comment: A depletion type MOSFET is not what is being asked here. A depletion type nMOS is simply an nMOS with a zero, or a negative threshold voltage, allowing conduction in a lower voltage value compared to an ordinary nMOS. Instead of opening the circuit, a depletion type nMOS will enter saturation at a lower VG voltage, closing the circuit at a lower voltage value.

Comment: @Cem I think the question is sufficiently vaguely worded that this could easily be considered a possible answer.

Comment: @Cem wait...are you saying that the channel of an N-channel, depletion mode MOSFET will conduct as the gate becomes sufficiently negative with respect to the source? I think that is the opposite of true, as the second graph here demonstrates.

Comment: No, I do not mean that at all, an N-channel depletion mode MOSFET will conduct just as an N-channel enhancement mode MOSFET, with the only difference being the requirement of an even lower voltage at the gate to start conducting.

Comment: It is simply that my interpretation of the question is "A device which will conduct BELOW V and will not conduct above the said V", V being the gate voltage. This can be achieved with a single pMOS.

Comment: Cem is correct. About what I meant by the question.

Answer (score 4):

Many ways to do this. A few ideas:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBnHa7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The third example might require some explanation if you are not familiar with JFETs: normally the channel of J1 is open, but if you apply a sufficiently negative (relative to ground) voltage to the gate, it will "pinch off". A depletion-mode MOSFET would work as J1 also, but that's a rather esoteric part. I can't say I've ever encountered a JFET used in this application either, since JFETs are usually more expensive, not present in my parts drawer in great quantities, can't usually switch large currents, etc.

The first example works great if your load voltage is the same as your logic voltage. Not always the case.

The middle example simply demonstrates inverting the logic before applying it to the gate of M2. Here the load voltage can be anything within the capabilities of M2, shown here as 24VDC.

And of course, M1 and M2 could be replaced by their BJT equivalents, with the addition of an appropriate resistor to limit base current.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly generic solution is to use an analogue switch. It is a device that behaves very much like a relay in that it has an input that can switch on or off internal transistors. You can get these devices in SPDT format. You haven't stated what current or voltage you need to switch so it may be a problem using this device but it's worth consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here looking for the answer to the same question, but specifically for a single component that is a "default - ON" transistor.  After reading up more on some of the previous answers and checking with other sites it looks like a JFET fits the bill.  There are some good diagrams here (https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_5.html) that show this type of transistor has an "n" semiconductor all the way from the source to the drain with the "p" on the sides.  (BJT or MOSFET pnp transistor is a sandwich with wires connected to the bread so current must flow through all three layers; a JFET is like connecting the wires to just the meat so it never has to go through the bread)  Applying a voltage to the gate enlarges the depletion zone, which constricts current to flow through a thinner region of the "n" layer. Eventually the depletion zones grow to "pinch off" the current completely.